# Entry element for mm:ss with MonoTouch.Dialog?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am giving a try to MonoTouch and MonoTouch.Dialog and was wondering what would be the best way to create a Time entry element for minutes and seconds only. The TimeElement only seems to support hours and minutes.

I am very new to the whole framework, so I am wondering if there a way to create a text entry element with sort of a "##:##" mask and use a numeric keypad to populate the minutes and seconds?

A cooler option would be to use a section that would take the user to a view with two "Picker Views" (rotating wheels) for minutes and seconds, but I am not there yet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoTouch.Dialog's source code is available on Github (https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/tree/master/MonoTouch.Dialog).

There, have a look at the implementation of the **DateElement** (https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements.cs#L1827)

To get you a `TimeElementMinutesSeconds`, all you have to do is (untested) abuse the count down mode. It will offer hours and minutes, but you can just interpret them as minutes and seconds:

```
public class TimeElementMinutesSeconds : DateTimeElement {
        public TimeElementMinutesSeconds (string caption, DateTime date) : base (caption, date)
        {
        }

        public override string FormatDate (DateTime dt)
        {
            DateTime dtLocal = GetDateWithKind (dt).ToLocalTime ();
return string.Format("{0:##}:{1:##}"dtLocal.Hours, dtLocal.Minutes);
        }

        public override UIDatePicker CreatePicker ()
        {
            var picker = base.CreatePicker ();
            picker.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.CountDownTimer;
            return picker;
        }
    }
```

If that doesn't get you near enough, you can create your own picker and return that instead.

Comment: This is a great idea, unfortunately, the CountDownTimer mode still shows "Hours" and "Min" for the two picker views. Looks like I might have to create my own picker..

Comment: UIDatePicker manages a UIPickerView as a subview. You should be able to access it and rename the spinners.

Comment: Very helpful, I am **almost** there and will post the code once I get it to work. Found the UILabel that contains the "hours" string in the subviews and changed the text, but the text didn't show as expected in the picker. Any idea about this one?    UILabel hoursLabel = (from v in pickerView.Subviews
                           where (v is UILabel) && "Hours".Equals (((UILabel)v).Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                           select v).SingleOrDefault () as UILabel;
hoursLabel.Text = "Minutes";

Comment: Probably depends *when you are doing this* and when *UIKit* is setting the text. But I really recommend you create your own picker element. Should be easier and more flexible.